# How to change Lubuntu's default terminal?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, gnome-terminal

I have tried to change the terminal by either using the GUI:

> Preferences -> LXQT Settings -> Session Settings -> Default Applications -> Terminal Emulation

or using the terminal with the following code:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

But I have had no luck changing the default terminal of my Lubuntu device.
Any ideas how could I change it?
I don't like the appearance of the current terminal.

Comment: How are you starting the terminal?

Comment: @OrganicMarble using Ctrl + Alt + T.

Comment: Working fine in Xubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a single setting for this yet.  However if you change them all to  `x-terminal-emulator`, which is a symlink, you can then later easily change them all at once by using `update-alternatives` as you already tried.

### To change the global shortcut key's terminal:

Open *Preferences > LXQT Settings > Shortcut Keys* and double click on the item that has the shortcut you wish to change.

[image: Global Actions Manager window]

And edit the command.

[image: Edit Action dialog]

### To change terminal used by *PCManFM-Qt*, (file manager and desktop):

From the *PCManFM-Qt File Manager* menu open *Edit > Preferences* and select the *Advanced* tab, and *Terminal Emulator* field.

[image: Advanced tab of PCManFM-Qt preferences dialog]

### Default for terminal based programs (`.desktop` files with `Terminal=true`):

#### Run from `lxqt-panel` (panel and menu):

Set by *Preferences > LXQT Settings > Session Settings*, *Default Applications* tab, and *Terminal Emulation* field.

[image: LXQT Session Settings Window]

#### Run from PCManFM-Qt (file manager and desktop)

Always `xterm` in Lubuntu 18.10!

Should use *PCManFM-Qt* settings, and has been fixed for 19.04.

Comment: On 16.04 there's no `lxqt-panel` but instead `lxpanelctl config` and then `lxpanelctl restart`.