# Change default terminal to Konsole in Lubuntu 19.04

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

I cannot change the default terminal from QTerminal to Konsole.

First I use `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`, but nothing changed (I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Following the steps in this link:

[How to change Lubuntu's default terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120709/how-to-change-lubuntus-default-terminal)

I have to add a new shortcut. However, in this step:

[image: Set keyboard shortcut]

it doesn't recognize the keyboard shortcut as I type, or even fire the default QTerminal. How do I change that keyboard shortcut? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.17/alternative_configurator.html?highlight=alternatives

From menu select Preferences -> Alternatives.Configurator, then X-terminal-emulator allows you to select from the list of installed terminals.

[image]

*I haven't tested it (and aren't running 19.04), so don't know if the effect is immediate, or you need to logout/login for it to work.*

Though if it's only CTRL+ALT+T you want to change, I'd suggest :-

From Menu select Preferences -> LXQt settings -> Shortcut Keys

https://manual.lubuntu.me/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html?highlight=shortcut

Comment: I can't even set the keyboard shortcut. For example, when setting the shortcut, the dialog I posted above popped up, right? Then I click on the `Shortcut` button to start capturing the key, however `Ctrl + Alt + T` aren't recognised! `Ctrl + Alt + ABC...` works, but not `T`

Comment: I suspect this issue relates to "*We made the SUPER key the default shortcut for opening the menu. This is a no brainer. Unfortunately, I discovered this makes the Openbox SUPER key combos not work. LXQt does not consider Openbox the canonical window manager of the desktop environment, so they won't do anything to fix this.*" is your issue, I don't have time to explore this further for you currently, but it maybe helpful  (https://phab.lubuntu.me/T59)   Sorry currently I don't have time to chase this down right now (or refresh myself on that task), but I suspect it contains your answer